# Put unorderedlist from app component into nav element in index.html

Tags: html, angular

In index.html I have defined the structure page.

```
<body>
  <app-root>
    <header></header>
    <nav></nav>
    <section></section>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
  </app-root>
</body>
```

In my app.component I have defined unorodered list.

```
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O Nas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dokumenty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
```

How can I make in angular 4 to inject these ul element into nav element in index?
Is it connected with selector in app.component.ts?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

- Create an new component for un-ordered list.
- Inject that component with the selector `<nav-component></nav-component>`.

**Solution 2**
 - Create a global variable and store the listed text as JSON object.

example:

```
let nav=[{name :'Strona główna', url:'../bla/bla'},
        {name :'O Nas', url:'../bla/bla'}
        {name :'Historia', url:'../bla/bla'}]
```

- Access the data through your app.service
- Generate the dynamic Un-ordered list using this data.

  example:`<ul><li "ngfor a in nav"> {{ a.name }}</li></ul>`

Comment: Can you give me an example of app.service to access these data, data in JSON can be stored in object in export class AppComponent?

Answer (score 0):

You've misplaced your HTML. The HTML you specified inside `<app-root></app-root>` should move to the file `app.component.html` and the list you specified should be inserted as is into that file as well:

index.html:

```html
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

app.component.html:

```html
<header></header>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Strona główna</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">O Nas</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Historia</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dokumenty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Galeria</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<section></section>
<aside></aside>
<footer></footer>
```